# Attempting Tridiagonal Gauss-Jordan Elimination Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

As you probably guessed from the title, I'm attempting to do tridiagonal GaussJordan elimination. I'm trying to do it without the default solver. My answers aren't coming out correct and I need some assistance as to where the error is in my code.

I'm getting different values for A/b and x, using the code I have.

```
n = 4;

#Range for diagonals
ranged = [15 20];
rangesd = [1 5];

#Vectors for tridiagonal matrix
supd = randi(rangesd,[1,n-1]);
d = randi(ranged,[1,n]);
subd = randi(rangesd,[1,n-1]);

#Creates system Ax+b
A = diag(supd,1) + diag(d,0) + diag(subd,-1)

b = randi(10,[1,n])

#Uses default solver
y = A/b


function x = naive_gauss(A,b);

#Forward elimination
for k=1:n-1
      for i=k+1:n
           xmult = A(i,k)/A(k,k);
           for j=k+1:n
             A(i,j) = A(i,j)-xmult*A(k,j);
           end
           b(i) = b(i)-xmult*b(k);
      end
end
#Backwards elimination
x(n) = b(n)/A(n,n);
for i=n-1:-1:1
   sum = b(i);
   for j=i+1:n
     sum = sum-A(i,j)*x(j);
   end
   x(i) = sum/A(i,i)
end
end

x
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is correct. The value of `y` that you compare against is wrong.

you have `y=A/b`, but the correct syntax to get the solution of the system should be **`y=A\b`**.